# PHP strtotime result is diffent in php7.3.2 and php7.3.1

Tags: php, strtotime

just less than 1900,more than is normal.
php version is 7
example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('PRC');
$sbegintime = strtotime('1900-01-01 00:00:00');
var_dump($sbegintime);exit;
```

php7.3：-2209017600
php7.2：-2209017943
why?

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/MHvIs

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden put test.php and visist in chrome

Comment: Heed the warning on https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php and try with Asia/Shanghai instead, does that change anything?

Comment: @deceze  nothing changes

Comment: Nothing in the [release notes](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.3.2) indicates a change in this area. (The behavior changes in [7.3.2](https://3v4l.org/Ionr7)). Looks like it has something to do with [the timezone](https://3v4l.org/MlN92). Same results for [Asia/Shanghai](https://3v4l.org/GBK0a).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is subtracting these two times (in 1927) giving a strange result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [famous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result) relating to a historical event in China wherein the clocks were set back 352 seconds on New Years Day, 1928, meaning you can get unexpected results when dealing with dates before that time. **Apparantly PHP has updated the timezone offset for that timezone (for pre 1928 dates) , from +8:00 to +8:05**. (*Some other change that I can't find right now, but is mentioned in the linked question, accounts for the offset changing from 352 to 343*).

```
/* php7.2 (+8:00) */

(new DateTime('1900-01-01 00:00:00', new DateTimezone("PRC")))->format(\DateTime::ATOM); 
// 1900-01-01T00:00:00+08:00"

/* php7.3: (+8:05) */

(new DateTime('1900-01-01 00:00:00', new DateTimezone("PRC")))->format(\DateTimeInterface::ATOM);
// "1900-01-01T00:00:00+08:05"
```

The php7.3 changes don't call out this change specifically, but if you look at the changes to [php7.2.12](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.2.12) it says

> "Upgraded timelib to 2017.08."

and for [7.3.8](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.3.8) it says

> "Updated timelib to 2018.02."

Since [timelib](https://github.com/derickr/timelib) is the underlying library supporting PHP DateTime, a change implemented between those versions would be resposible, unfortunately I can't find a changelog.

Answer (score -3):

this notes from php strtotime documentation could help you.

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901
> 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates
> that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed
> integer.)
>
> Prior to PHP 5.1.0, not all platforms support negative timestamps,
> therefore your date range may be limited to no earlier than the Unix
> epoch. **This means that e.g. dates prior to Jan 1, 1970 will not work
> on Windows,** some Linux distributions, and a few other operating
> systems.

Comment: *Prior to PHP 5.1.0…*

Comment: i don't think so，i test in php7 and Windows is normal

Comment: What is the result of `echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $sbegintime);`? I test both linux and win10 and have the same result '1900-01-01 00:00:00'

Comment: centos 1900-01-01 00:00:00int(-2209017600)

Comment: win 1900-01-01 00:00:00int(-2209017943)